# convert datetime to string in sql select query

Tags: c#

I am trying to display data from database on datagriview and  export data from data grid view to csv, my sqlite database dateformat is DateTime

```
2012-02-20 16:42:10.000
```

displayed on datagridview is in the format of

```
20/02/2012 16:42:10
```

my select statment  is , i want to display on datagridview datetime column as the same format which in database

```
m_dbConnection.Open();

            SQLiteCommand myCommand = new SQLiteCommand();
            myCommand.Connection = m_dbConnection;


            myCommand.CommandText = "select CompanyId,CONVERT(VARCHAR,DateTime, 103) as date_issued,Serial,ShortDeviceId,MatricolaA,Upper(Targa),VerbaliRuleOnePoints,VerbaliMissedNotificationDescription  from  VerbaliData";
            //myCommand.Connection = myConn;
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            SQLiteDataAdapter myAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(myCommand);
            //myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;
            myAdapter.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
            this.dataGridView1.Refresh();
            if (dataGridView1.RowCount > 0)
            {
                string value = "";
                DataGridViewRow dr = new DataGridViewRow();
                StreamWriter swOut = new StreamWriter("I:/final test/finaltest12.csv");

                //write header rows to csv
                for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (i > 0)
                    {
                        swOut.Write(",");
                    }
                    swOut.Write(dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText);
                }

                swOut.WriteLine();

                //write DataGridView rows to csv
                for (int j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (j > 0)
                    {
                        swOut.WriteLine();
                    }

                    dr = dataGridView1.Rows[j];

                    for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        if (i > 0)
                        {
                            swOut.Write(",");
                        }
                        // Datetime column content transformed in a formatted string....
                        if(i == 1)
                            {
                              object cellValue = dr.Cells[i].Value;
                                  value = (cellValue == DBNull.Value ? 
                                 string.Empty : Convert.ToDateTime(cellValue).ToString("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss"));
                                 }   
                            value = dr.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
                        //replace comma's with spaces
                        value = value.Replace(',', ' ');
                        //replace embedded newlines with spaces
                        value = value.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");

                        swOut.Write(value);
                    }
                }
                swOut.Close();
            }

            m_dbConnection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: If you tell him to give you "DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss", you'll get it... why not use a "YYYY\-MM\-DD HH\:mm\:ss.fff" instead?

Comment: as per i know the sql query always return as object you only need to explicitly cast the date to string.. but u here are directly giving the result of the query to dataGridView.. jux a check plz use.. cast(DateTime as varchar(103))

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Dataformatstring`

Add Dataformatstring like

```
Dataformatstring="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.s" in bound field column
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to not cast your DateTime object to a string in your SQL statement:

```
myCommand.CommandText = "select CompanyId, date_issued, Serial, ShortDeviceId, " + 
  "MatricolaA, Upper(Targa), VerbaliRuleOnePoints, VerbaliMissedNotificationDescription " +
  "from VerbaliData";
```

I don't think "Upper(Targa)" is going to work, though.

Whatever, right? That's not the issue here.

Once you're done with that, handle your DateTime object in your code as you are parsing through the data:

```
if (i == 1)
{
  object cellValue = dr.Cells[i].Value;
  value = (cellValue == DBNull.Value) ? 
    string.Empty :
    Convert.ToDateTime(cellValue).ToString("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss");
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: i have already tried this its still the same its exporting what actually is int he datagrid view so, i need to change the datetime column on select statment